# Node JS : Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] While using ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-modules, es6-class

Route File

```
  scoreboardroute.js

  import { scoreRouteController } from '../controllers/scoreboardcontroller';

  const SCOREROUTE = app => {
     app.route('/getAllScores').get(scoreRouteController.getAllScores);
  };

  export { SCOREROUTE };
```

Controller File

```
scoreboardcontroller.js
import { scoreBoardModel } from '../model/scoreboardmodel';

class scoreRouteController {

 getAllScores = (req, res) => {
    scoreBoardModel.getAllScoresList((err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.send(response);
    });
 };
}

export { scoreRouteController };
```

Model File:

```
scoreboardmodel.js
import { db } from './db';

class scoreBoardModel {
  getAllScoresList = callback => {
    db.query('Select * from users', (err,response) => {
        callback(err, response);
    });
  }
};

export { scoreBoardModel };
```

I was trying to use ES6 features like class and arrow functions inside my application. While I'm trying to execute this code it hit the following error. I don't know what went wrong. And I'm really new for node JS server.
So, Can anyone please help me to get rid of this error.

**Error**:

node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
    at SCOREROUTE (/app/routes/scoreboardroute.js:4:32)
    at Object. (/server.js:26:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)

Comment: You're treating classes like instances. It would be simpler to just use objects, as none of your methods use `this`.

Comment: I just wanna try ES6. That's why I'm jumping in into this. Can you please tell me what's going wrong in this approach?

Comment: I told you what's going wrong: you're treating classes like instances. If you really want to use classes for this, you have to new them up somewhere.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate this one?

Comment: Then go and read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes. If you want to use these features, you'll have to learn the basics of them.

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe . I figure out what went wrong. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding the answer.

While importing the class I'm using like Object import. So, changed it like

```
import scoreRouteController from '../controllers/scoreboardcontroller';
```

And I'm not going to use so many instances for my application. So, I assign static keyword for my every function inside my class.

```
static getAllScores = (req, res) => {.....
```

While exporting I was not exporting an Obj. I changed into default class export.

```
export default scoreRouteController;
```

And finally, it works.